# Players who join my world can't open chests

Tags: terraria-mobile

So my friend joined my world on Terraria mobile edition and she went to open a chest that I had placed. It would not let her open it. It just took her to her inventory.
Then I made a new world and she then joined but she went to open a chest from the dungeon that she had unlocked and it wouldn't even let her open that. We had of course defeated skeleteon and I was able to open all chests in the dungeon and placed by me.

Could someone please tell me why she can't open chests in worlds made by me and if I can fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified Android or iOS edition

Comment: Were you in the chest when the other player was in the chest?